# Зачем нужен Netty, если Jetty и так использует NIO?

Tags: java, jetty, netty

Насколько я понимаю, Jetty в последних версиях так же использует NIO, следовательно у него так же есть epoll(если говорим в контексте линукса), и он может прекрасно обрабатывать запросы в одном потоке, зачем тогда нужен Netty Framework?
P.S. Вопрос, скорее всего, глупый, заранее извиняюсь.

Answer (score 0):

#### Netty

Событийно-ориентированный фреймворк для построения высокопроизводительных, асинхронных веб-приложений

#### Jetty

Легковесный контейнер сервлетов и HTTP-Клиент

У них  в принципе разный спектр использования. Netty входит в основу таких фреймворков как например Spring WebFlux и в отличии от Jetty, у него намного лучше масштабируемость, пропускная способность и соответсвенно отказоустойчивость.
Jetty подходит для маленьких, местечковых приложений "для себя"

Надеюсь, дал ясность.

Спасибо

Comment: Не совсем понятно, исходя из чего Netty имеет большую пропускную способность, они построены на одной технологии, не говоря о том, что какой-нибудь reactor-netty еще делает back pressure, что может влиять на производительность.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не понимаете зачем нужен back pressure. При правильном использовании он защищает потребитель (веб сервер) от перегрузки